# Finding open subgroups of profinite groups from description as an inverse limit

Tags: topological-groups, profinite-groups

For the profinite group $\widehat{\mathbb Z} := \varprojlim_n \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ (which ofcourse actually has a ring structure as well), you can show its open subgroups are precisely the groups $n \widehat{\mathbb Z}$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$, and each such subgroups has quotient group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. In an informal sense, I'd like to say you can "see" all its open subgroups and their quotients occuring in the defining limit $\varprojlim_n \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

I am wondering if a similar description of the open normal subgroups and their quotients exist for $\widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times = \varprojlim_n (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$, or more generally for any profinite group with an explicit descripition as an inverse limit of finite groups, such as for example a profinite completion $\widehat{G} := \varprojlim_N G/N$ of a discrete group (where $N$ ranges over all normal subgroups of finite index).

For $\widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times$, I believe for any $n$ the map $\widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times \to (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ is surjective, but I'm not (yet) able to prove this. For this I think it is helpful that the maps $(\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z)^\times \to (\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)^\times$ are surjective if $n \mid m$. Once I know $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^\times \to (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ is surjective however, I then get an isomorphism
$$
\widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times/(1 + n\widehat{\mathbb Z}) \cap \widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times \cong (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times.
$$
This is useful since $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$, being profinite, has a neighbourhoodbasis of the identity given by open normal subgroups, which we know are of the form $n \widehat{\mathbb Z}$. Therefore every open subgroup $U$ of $\widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times$ contains $(1 + n\widehat{\mathbb Z}) \cap \widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times$ for some $n$, and therefore $\widehat{\mathbb Z}^\times/U$ must be a quotient of $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Now, for any discrete group $G$, form its profinite completion $\widehat{G} = \varprojlim_N G/N$. Then the maps $\widehat{G} \to G/N$ are surjective for every normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, and in this case I know a proof: the composition $G \to \widehat{G} \to G/N$ is the quotient map and therefore surjective, so $\widehat{G} \to G/N$ must also be surjective. Is every open normal subgroup the kernel of such a map $\widehat{G} \to G/N$? Then it would hold that all quotients of $\widehat G$ by an open normal subgroup are isomorphic to $G/N$ for some $N$.

Comment: If you have an inverse system $\{X_i, \varphi_{ij},I\}$ where each $X_i$ is a non-empty compact Hausdorff topological space and each $\varphi_{ij}$ is surjective, for $j \leq i$, then the projections $\varphi_i \colon X \to X_i$ are also surjective, with $X = \varprojlim X_i$. Indeed, take $x_i \in X_i$ and let $S_j = \varphi_{ji}^{-1}(\{x_i\})$ whenever $ i \leq j$. Since each transition map is surjective, the $S_i$ are non-empty compact Hausdorff and they form an inverse system. The (non-empty) inverse limit $S = \varprojlim S_j$ gives you an element $x\in X$ such that $\varphi_i(x) = x_i$.